# Java Encryption and Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, hash, aes

I want  know whether encryption and Decryption is possible in Java without using security key?I saw different examples but all are using security key to decrypt. Pls help

Comment: It's not about Java. Principally you need some secret to securely encrypt / decrypt data. How would you prevent an unauthorized party to decrypt data if it would be possible without any key? You placed a *hash* tag, but that's a one way function, not encryption

Comment: Just hiding text without key is commonly called "obfuscation" i.e. the act of obscuring the message. Also see [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) to why a key is needed. Of course you can hide the decryption key through obfuscation as well - theoretically that doesn't make much of a difference w.r.t. security (i.e. you'd still have none in a cryptographic sense) but now you've at least got *fewer* bits to obfuscate.

Answer (score 0):

In modern cryptography, a cipher is defined to have a key as input. So if you use the modern definition, encryption and decryption is impossible without a key. Without it, you don't achieve any security at all.

You can at most *obfuscate* text, e.g. by ROT13 over existing text. You could also use base64 with a mixed alphabet to gain some security. However, you could see that as weak encryption with a static key (the alphabet).

So no, this is not possible.